# hello! I am new in php could please you tell me the answer. I am not getting Output for this PHP Program

Tags: php

why I am not getting output as a uid ?
this is my index.

```
<a href='my_posts.php?u_id=$user_id' class='list-group-item'>My Posts(<?php echo $post_count; ?>)</a>`
```

and this is my my_posts.php

```
<?php 
include('function.php');
user_posts(); 
?>
```

and this is my function.php

```
<?PHP 
function user_posts(){
global $con;
if(isset($_GET['u_id'])){
$u_id = $_GET['u_id'];
echo $u_id;
 }
}
?>`
```

Comment: Because `function.php` is not included anywhere

Comment: i have included it but getting same issue

Comment: Change your index to what the two answers say and you should be good to go

Comment: i already got changed but it prints $user_id as a result

Comment: It prints `$user_id` as a result because your URL probably looks like this: `my_posts.php?u_id=$user_id...`

Comment: "i already got changed but it prints $user_id as a result" — That's because that is what you typed in the link.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you should change you code like this:
`<a href='my_posts.php?u_id=<?php echo $user_id;?>' class='list-group-item'>My Posts(<?php echo $post_count; ?>)</a>`
`

Comment: i tried to change this code but still getting same issue

Comment: Where your HTML  came from？Printed by php ?

Answer (score 0):

Here's how your index should look:

```
<?php
$user_id = 12; // Example value
$post_count = 3; // Example value
echo "<a href='my_posts.php?u_id=$user_id' class='list-group-item'>My Posts($post_count)</a>";
```

You can remove the `$user_id=12` and `$post_count=3` in your implementation.

Your `my_posts.php` and `function.php` can stay as they are.

Edit: in your `function.php` you could additionally check if `$_GET['u_id']` is of type integer using [is_int()](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/function.is-int.php)

Answer (score 0):

There are several errors in your provided code
`$user_id` is not initialized anywhere, the function `user_posts()` **echoes** `$u_id` and not `$user_id` which you are printing.

Echoing inside a function is incorrect if you want to access its output, `return` should be used instead. Read more about `return` in [php manual](http://php.net/manual/en/function.return.php)

```
<a href='my_posts.php?u_id=**$user_id**' class='list-group-item'>
```

This syntax  is also incorrect as it is, php variables need to be present inside `<?php ?>` tags else they will be treated like simple text.

**Solution:**

```
<?php 
  include('function.php');
  $user_id = user_posts(); // You can now use $user_id to print the output of user_posts()
  echo "<a href='my_posts.php?u_id={$user_id}' class='list-group-item'>My Posts({$post_count})</a>";
?>
```

function.php

```
<?PHP 
  function user_posts(){
    global $con;
    if(isset($_GET['u_id'])){
       $u_id = $_GET['u_id'];
       return $u_id; // echo changed to return
    }
  }
?>
```

Answer (score -2):

simply change single quotes to double quotes in anchor tag. In single quotes you can't put php variables.

```
<a href="my_posts.php?u_id=$user_id" class='list-group-item'>My Posts(<?=$post_count?>)</a>
```

Comment: That's in PHP strings, not in HTML attribute values.

Comment: Yes. I've tried it. I didn't need to because I already know how PHP and HTML work, but I tried it.

Comment: @Ayyappaamara Just stumbled upon your answer but man you are rude. As mentioned by @Quentin - `href="my_posts.php?u_id=$user_id"` is wrong unless used inside a php strings, for example `echo "href='my_posts.php?u_id=$user_id' "`. Learn to take criticism